# PHP Random Teacher Generator not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list of teachers & their departments, it's selected randomly in a different part of the code, that all works fine, it genereates a random teacher and the subject they teach (department). 
However, what I want to do is make it so you click one image of a teacher, then it somehow recognises which teacher you selected, then validates whether or not you clicked a teacher with a higher rating (the rating is stored in .TXT).
So for example, `Mr Smith` teaches `Geography` and has rating `3/10`. `Mr White` teaches `History` and has rating `7/10`. You reload the page, and both of those teachers come up, you have to pick who you think has a higher rating, and if you're right, you go to `correct.php`, if you're wrong you go to `incorect.php`

Here's the code. (I can't use $_GET[] btw because when I do, it reloads the page)

Who's got a higher rating?

```
<div class="text-1"><?php echo "Name: " . $teacher1 . "<br>" . "Department: " . $teacher1department . "<br>" . "Rating: " . $teacher1rating;?></div></br>
<div class="text-2"><br><?php echo "Name: " . $teacher2 . "<br>" . "Department: " . $teacher2department . "<br>" . "Rating: " . $teacher1rating;?></div></br>

<a href="?selected=2"><img src="icon.png" onclick="rating()" class="icon 2"></a><br>

<?php
    function rating() {
        /* Tells you who got the higher rating */
        if($teacher1rating > $teacher2rating) {
            $higherRating = $teacher1; 
        }
        if($teacher1rating < $teacher2rating) {
            $higherRating = $teacher2;
        }
    if (isset($_GET['selected'])) {
        if($_GET['selected'] == $higherRating) {
            header( 'Location: correct.php?teacher=' . $teacher1 );
        }
        if($_GET['selected'] != $higherRating) {
            header( 'Location: incorrect.php?teacher=' . $teacher2);
        }
    }
?>
```

Live version at http://hughchalmers.com/stackoverflow. When I release it, of course the rating won't be publically displayed

Comment: If you want to ensure the client isn't going to try cheat I would not pull and store the ratings client side, I would just pass the teacher ID (or whatever each teacher has as a unique identification) and check those server-side.

Comment: In your `a`-Tag, you have an URL as well as an event handler called `rating()`. But there is no JavaScript handler for it. What is the task of `rating()`? - I suggest you remove the URL in the `a`-Tag and write a JavaScript handler method called `rating()`. It's task is to recognize which teacher was selected and to call the URL with that information.

Comment: @NewToJS is right, storing the data client-side is a bad idea _unless_ you encrypt it, then that would be possible.

Comment: It's encrypted above. There is more code above that, that's just the issue I'm having trouble with.

Comment: +peter_the_oak, the a tag is the problem, I need another way that isn't $_GET. Basically all I need is a way to make it so when you click on an image, it will create variable $guess = 1; or $guess = 2;